# Brief statusbar change during network access

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5

Here's a question... how to update the statusbar (OSX) quickly for a few seconds of network access, using PyQt5. It's mainly for show, but you know how that goes. Here's the code in question:

```
def process_item(rownumber):
    window.statusBar().showMessage("Server Activity...")
    QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.WaitCursor))
    message = []                        # 
    item_name = Listing[rownumber]      # setup message to
    message.append("rename")            # TCP server
    message.append(item_name)           #
    retval = joe_sender.sendmessage(message)  # TCP send
    app_data = retval                         # TCP return  
    QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
    window.statusBar().showMessage("")
```

There's a few seconds of "dead time" while the data goes back and forth to a simple TCP server on a remote machine. I wanted to get the status bar to say "Network access" or something similar during this time, but the change doesn't take effect until about 80% of the delay is done. Is there any way I can speed this up, making it take effect instantly? As it is now, it changes and changes back faster than you can see it. I've tried a call to `window.update()` but that had no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: call to `QApplication().processEvents()` after `window.statusBar().showMessage("Server Activity...")`

Comment: Had to lose the parentheses after `QApplication` for a replacement of `QApplication.processEvents()` and it works like a charm! Thanks!